# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UnitConversionPipe')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've 2 pipes with names **UnitConversionPipe** and **ConvertAndFormat**. **Both are in different modules and I am consuming UnitConvertionPipe inside ConvertAndFormat pipe**. After I re-export ConvertAndFormat pipe in barrel file (index.ts) I am getting the following test case error

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UnitConversionPipe')
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UnitConversionPipe')
```

But this issue is not coming when it remove from barrel file. But it's required to re-export the same in barrel file as well.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are both pipes exported from the same barrel file? Do you import UnitConvertionPipe for ConvertAndFormat from the same barrel file?

Comment: Hi @Shlang, both are in different barrel files.

Comment: Ah ok, the thing is that this error usually indicates a cyclical dependency, but it is hard to tell without knowing all the places these directives are used.

Comment: Hi @Shlang , UnitConvertionPipe  is using 2 more other pipes than the ConvertAndFormat pipe.

Comment: To check for circular dependencies: `npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./`